# Radio field list giving only last value in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a radio field with some value (from 1 to 5) which I need basically to retrieve the user's input value. I put it inside a foreach loop in blade template but, when i try to retrieve the value, it takes just the last value of the for loop (which, in this case, is 5). Even though I select other values it always gets value 5.
Here some code.

```
$gradings = range(1, 5);
```

template

```
               @foreach ($learning_objectives as $key=> $lo)
                  <tr>
                    <td id="learning_obj">{{ $lo->name }}</td>
                    @foreach ($gradings as $grade)
                    <td>
                        <input name="grade{{ $lo->name }}" type="radio" id="radio{{ $grade }}" class="form-check {{ $grade }}" value="{{$grade}}" required="">
                        <label for="radio{{ $grade }}"></label>
                        <input type="hidden" name="grade[{{ $key }}]" value="{{ $grade }}">

                    </td>
                    @endforeach
                    <td>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="note[]" id="note" />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  @endforeach
```

controller

```
$grade_list = $request->grade; //probably that is the main issue, but I don't know how to get this value
    $fail = $request->fail;
    $mi = new MultipleIterator();
    $mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($learning_objectives));
    $mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($note));
    $mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($grade_list));
    foreach ($mi as $value) {
        list($lo, $n, $g) = $value;
        $mission_entry = new MissionEntry();
        $mission_entry->learning_objective_id = $lo['id'];
        $mission_entry->grade = $g; //this value is always stored as 5, even though I select other values
        $mission_entry->comment = $n;
        $mission_entry->student_id = $student->id;
        $mission_entry->mission_id = $mission_id;
        $mission_entry->log_entry_id = $log_entry->id;
        $mission_entry->save();
    }
```

Comment: You have problem with `$gradings` or `$grade_list = $request->grade;`?

Comment: $grade_list. it's always retrieving an array with a 5 value, instead the value I am actually giving

Comment: Well `$request->grade` would access the _hidden_ field you put in there ... You need to access the parameter with name corresponding to whatever `name="grade{{ $lo->name }}"` actually resulted in.

Comment: Ok, the purpose of the hidden field was to avoid accessing the field  name="grade{{ $lo->name }}". Anyway, shall I try to create another array with the grade and the $lo->name, in order to retrieve the right value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question because in the end I found the answer. It may be useful for whomever has a similar case.
Basically, I removed the hidden input and use the name field of the radio field. The problem was that in the name field I had some variables with spaces so I had to find a quite verbose solution.

template

```
@foreach ($mission_entry as $key=> $lo)
                  <tr>
                    <td id="learning_obj">{{ $lo->learning_objective->name }}</td>
                    @foreach ($gradings as $grade)
                    <td>
                        <input name="grade{{ str_replace(' ', '', $lo->learning_objective->name) }}" {{ ($grade == $lo->grade) ? 'checked' : '' }} type="radio" id="radio{{ $grade }}" class="form-check {{ $grade }}" value="{{$grade}}" required="">
                        <label for="radio{{ $grade }}"></label>

                    </td>
                    @endforeach
                    <td>
                      <input type="text" value="{{ $lo->comment }}" class="form-control" name="note[]" id="note" />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  @endforeach
```

First I remove the spaces in the input name.

```
$grade_list = array();
    foreach ($learning_objectives as $key => $lo) {
        $string = $lo['name'];
        $string = str_replace(' ', '', $string);
        $grade_list[] = 'grade' . $string;
    }
```

This creates an array with the names without any space and last, but not least, I can retrieve the values.

```
foreach ($grade_list as $key => $g) {
        $grades[] = $request->$g;
    }
```

Hope someone finds it useful.